# How to measure brute force speed of a computer for a give cipher with given number of keys for second for a given key space

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, symmetric, brute-force-attack, performance

As I understood brute force attack is measured in number of keys which in turns give time required based on speed of computer

It is quite interesting find out how effective an arbitrary computer is and estimate to total time required to try all number of keys in a given key space.

Are there any tools available to practically estimate the effectiveness of a computer to try all number of key in a key space to brute force attack block cipher.

For example

```
key length: 32 
key space:  2 ** 32
Time: 
   10 ^ 9 keys/sec = 4 sec
   10 ^ 12 keys/sec = 4 ms
```

Theoretically we can calculate with all these assumption. But, is there any way/tool/application to measure speed of a computer and how many keys it can try per second without trying all number of keys in key space.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad. What algorithm you mean? Brute-forcing DES is different from brute-forcing AES-256 GCM.

Also if you have some scheme where password is derived using Argon2, then password derivation itself can be essentially slower than the actual encryption.

It depends also on implementation of brute-forcing. Less skilled attacker can try every possible key and will perform the whole sequence of the algorithm that is being brute-forced. Where as skilled attacker will be aware about known attacks on particular algorithm and will implement brute-forcing more efficiently; depending on algorithm this can be a few bits, can be also much more.

Try to formulate your question more precisely. Then you will get more precise answers.